# Does Visual Studio 2013 run applications with higher permission than manually running the .exe?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, permissions, windows-8.1

I noticed something really strange. If I run the following code from VS2013, it works as expected. However, when I manually double-click the compiled .exe, it doesn't. This leads me to believe that VS2013 somehow launches apps with elevated permissions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("You have 5 seconds to open a Metro App. \nThen we'll try setting the TaskBar as the foreground window.\n\n");
    Sleep(5000);

    printf("Setting Taskbar as foreground window now... \n");
    SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(L"Shell_TrayWnd", NULL));

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

When running from VS2013: Even if a Metro App is open (taking up the full screen), after the taskbar is set as the foreground window, the user is taken back to the desktop.

When double-clicking the .exe: If a Metro App is the foreground window, nothing happens.

As a side note, I've attempted to right-click and "Run as Administrator" however, that still has no effect. Which is even more confusing. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Also, I'm running Windows 8.1 Preview.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?  I built your project using VS2010 on Win7 64bit and got the same behavior whether I launched from the debugger or .exe.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to make it more clear. I'm running the Windows 8.1 Preview and when I said "Modern app" I meant "Metro app". Anywho, it seems this issue is specific to the Metro UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with folks at Microsoft about this. It looks like it's the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that's slightly inaccurate. 
"The foreground process is being debugged." should be something like "The calling process is being debugged." It's going to be updated soon.

Answer (score 0):

No, it runs the debugged application with the same permissions.

However, if you [read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see that permissions have nothing to do with it. But being debugged is listed explicitly.

Comment: Thanks MSalters! That page does specifically that if "The foreground process is being debugged" then it has the ability to call SetForegroundWindow(), otherwise it will fail. However, in the scenarios I'm describing the foreground process is a Metro app which is not being debugged.

Comment: Well, "running from VS2013" is the same as begin debugged, and then it works. If double-clicked, it's not debugged, so it won't.

Comment: But it says "The foreground process is being debugged," which is different from "The calling process is being debugged." In this case, the calling process is my desktop app (which is being debugged) and the foreground process is any random Metro app (which is definitely not being debugged to my knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply "double-click" an exe for a WinRT app.  There is a different app launch model which creates the process for the exe.  This is done through the package application/activation which is also what the designer does.  So if you F5 the application it will run because it uses the WinRT activation mechanisms.

Comment: Hey Tim! Sorry, maybe I was unclear. I'm not double-clicking a Metro app exe. Here're the repro steps I'm talking about: 
1. Compile the code listed above into a classic desktop .exe  
2. Double click the .exe
3. As soon as the app opens, it will sleep for 5 seconds. During that time launch any Metro app (let's say the mail app).
4. After the 5 seconds expires, the task bar will be set as the foreground window and the user should be taken to the classic desktop. 

The actual result though is that SetForegroundWindow() call fails. What's funny though is if it's launched via VS2013, it succeeds.